# Enable/Disable CLEARTYPE

Tags: c#, user32, cleartype

I'm using the following code to try to force enable CLEARTYPE option in user32.dll but don't work in representation of image from report text.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
                uint uiAction,
                uint uiParam,
                bool pvParam,
                uint fWinIni
            );

            const uint SPI_SETCLEARTYPE = 0x1049;
            const uint SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
            const uint SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCLEARTYPE, 0, true, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
```

any advice?

Comment: WinForms or WPF? What control/action you want to apply? You can do it with managed code, no need to use pinvoke

Comment: 3rd party library I need global solution

Comment: Can not answer as I don't know what 3rd party you are using. Your current approach will (if success) change system wide setting, which effect Windows and other applications. Let honor user choices. They can simply turn back to your app just because you change a small setting they don't want.

Comment: As I see in dll of 3rd party library the majority of controllers heredate the CLEARTYPE value from user32 i just want to change the top value (user32) to change all library of the 3rd party